# Are the units of rate constants affected if we have more than one substance in the rate law

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

$$A+B \rightarrow C$$ $$rate = k[A] [B]$$ 
[A]= x mol of A/L
[B]= y mol of B/L 
So why the unit of the rate constant is merely $$L/M$$ not having mol of A or mol of B?

Comment: Why the unit of weight is merely a kilogram, and not _"kilogram of lead"_ when you weigh lead, or _"kilogram of fluff"_ when you weigh fluff?

Comment: The rate has units of concentration/time  or $\ce{mol dm^{-3}s^{-1}}$. As this is an equation the left had side equals the right hand side both in value and units thus the rate constant $k$ has units  1/(concentration x time) or  $\ce{dm^{3}mol^{-1} s^{-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

The heart of your problem is that you're assuming that there exist **different types of the unit *mole*.**

Consider the unit of length one meter. Take two meters of cotton thread, and two meters of jute thread. Place them together and you get a nice square of $1\times1 \text{ <unit of area>}$. Now what should the unit of area be? Should it be $=\text{cotton meter} \times \text{jute meter}$?

Well, it should NOT be $\text{cotton meter} \times \text{jute meter}$ because **a meter, being a *unit*, is same for all substances being measured.** A meter of jute is exactly the same length as a meter of cotton. Hence, the unit of area should be $\text{meter}^2$, which it always is.

Similarly, in your solution, you are assuming there exist two different types of the unit mole, one for $x$ and one for $y$. However, there is only one fundamental unit, and it measures the same amount of substance for both $x$ and $y$.

Hope it helps!